# How do I remove the space underneath text that is created by the FONT

Tags: html, css

[image] [image]

I had thought this issue was related to `line-height`, `padding`, `margins`, `display`, etc. etc. I thought maybe it had something to do with the parent element, but it turns out that the font is creating the space!

Is there a way to remove or adjust this space?

What I'd really like to do though is have it so the text is vertically centered. As you can see in the first picture, it doesn't line up vertically in the center.

I've created a Codepen here: https://codepen.io/kanekekoa/pen/GRPeBXz

```css
:root {
  --accent: #db1959;
  --accent-2: #8eb2a6;
  --accent-4: #f4fbfe;
  --accent-5: rgba(210, 215, 198, 0.2);
  --hb-pink: #db1959;
}

body {
  background-color: var(--hb-pink);
}

a {
  text-transform: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  box-sizing: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: inline-flex;
  font-weight: 700;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  background-color: var(--accent-4);
  color: var(--accent);
}

#fancy-font {
  font-family: Noto Sans Javanese, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<a id="fancy-font" href="#">Give us a shout!</a>

<a id="simple-font" href="#">Give us a shout!</a>
```

Comment: You need to edit your question to include the code which is not working. Or at least tell us which font it is.

Comment: Please provide your code. It is hard to debug without it. Preferably as a [MCVE]. Aslo keep in mind decenders. What about "p", "y". "j" etc.?

Comment: It looks like you are using display: flex; so you could add in align-item: center; to align vertically in the center.

Comment: Whoops! I had the code all ready in a codepen but I forgot to post the link. I've edited the question. Thanks @BrettDonald and JonP.

Comment: Here's the codepen just in case https://codepen.io/kanekekoa/pen/GRPeBXz

Comment: You're using a [Javanese variant of the Noto Sans font](https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Sans+Javanese?preview.text=%EA%A7%8B%EA%A6%A9%EA%A6%A4%EA%A6%B6%20abc%20test%20%EA%A7%8B%EA%A6%A9%EA%A6%A4%EA%A6%B6%20), which includes glyphs that are much taller than typical Latin characters.  It is a common yet often neglected issue when using a non-Latin font for Latin character set—as shown in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/google/fonts/issues/241) for Poppins font (a Devanagari font). An easiest solution might be finding a different typeface, specifically for Latin characters.

Comment: Hmm... if it is possible to keep the font, that would be ideal. Is there no solution with CSS to work around it? Otherwise, I can start looking for another font. Thanks @BumhanYu

Comment: Well, turns out there's a font in that family that doesn't have this issue. Simply Noto Sans. :) I'm still curious if there's a workaround. But it's not necessary. @BumhanYu if you'd like to post an Answer, I'll make it as correct.

Comment: As posted in the answer, the Javanese letters have much taller height than latin characters, and won't work nicely to enforce a typical baseline alignment if used for European languages. There might be some CSS hack to force the line-height, but it might be much sensible to pick an alternate typeface, as this particular font is designed to accommodate a particular language writing (i.e. Javanese)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Tl;dr. Choose a typeface that doesn't include non-latin characters

Your selected typeface "Noto Sans Javanese" is specifically crafted for Javanese character set, which has a much taller line height than typical latin characters.

[image: Noto Sans Javanese paragraph example]

That is, when using alongside with latin characters—or if used solely for latin character set—the non-Javanese letters might look like they're dangling from the top.

[image: inline text example]

[image: in-paragraph example]

[Noto Sans](https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Sans) is actually designed to support a wide range of languages scripts. Unless you are targeting specifically for a particular language (in this case, Javanese), you might not likely need a particular variant. Using a generic Noto Sans might be suffice, and will likely resolve your baseline alignment issue.